# Create canvas box based on json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

i wanted to make a box based on the json data width and height. however my box is already like this. can i ask how can i make a horizontal multiple box based on json data width and height? and not creating like this **ctx.rect(20, 21, 100, 100);**

You can access the code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-galois-nlp8g?file=/index.html

This is the code:

```
<canvas id="NodeList" width="900" height="2000"></canvas>

<script>
    var data = [{
            "name": "1",
            "x": 225,
            "y": 197,
            "width": 121,
            "height": 67,
            "bgColor": "#00FF00",
            "radius": 2,
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "2",
            "x": 225,
            "y": 297,
            "width": 121,
            "height": 67,
            "bgColor": "#00FF00",
            "radius": 2
        },    
        {
            "name": "3",
            "x": 225,
            "y": 397,
            "width": 121,
            "height": 67,
            "bgColor": "#00FF00",
            "radius": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "4",
            "x": 225,
            "y": 497,
            "width": 121,
            "height": 67,
            "bgColor": "#00FF00",
            "radius": 2
        },    
        {
            "name": "5",
            "x": 225,
            "y": 597,
            "width": 121,
            "height": 67,
            "bgColor": "#00FF00",
            "radius": 2
        }    
    ];
    var c = document.getElementById("NodeList");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    // for diagonal
    ctx.rect(20, 21, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillText(data[0].name, 25, 35);
    // end

    // for horizontal box
    ctx.rect(127, 21, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillText(data[0].name, 25, 35);
    ctx.rect(234, 21, 100, 100);
    ctx.rect(341, 21, 100, 100);
    //end
    
    ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="NodeList" width="900" height="2000"></canvas>

</body>

</html>

<script>
    var data = [{
        "name": "1",
        "x": 225,
        "y": 197,
        "width": 121,
        "height": 67,
        "bgColor": "#00FF00",
        "radius": 2,
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "2",
        "x": 225,
        "y": 297,
        "width": 121,
        "height": 67,
        "bgColor": "#00FF00",
        "radius": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "3",
        "x": 225,
        "y": 397,
        "width": 121,
        "height": 67,
        "bgColor": "#00FF00",
        "radius": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "4",
        "x": 225,
        "y": 497,
        "width": 121,
        "height": 67,
        "bgColor": "#00FF00",
        "radius": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "5",
        "x": 225,
        "y": 597,
        "width": 121,
        "height": 67,
        "bgColor": "#00FF00",
        "radius": 2
    }
    ];
    var c = document.getElementById("NodeList");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop through the data array
        const _data = data[i];
        ctx.beginPath(); // Call beginPath before drawing any shape
        ctx.rect(_data.x, _data.y, _data.width, _data.height);
        ctx.fillText(_data.name, _data.x + 10, _data.y + 10); // +10 means the offset
        ctx.stroke();
    }

</script>
```